# StyleSheet not Applied

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to style this HTML page using the style used here
https://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/BNNJjo

I have added the style reference and `<div>` tags.But the style is not properly applied.Please advice.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>User Validation</title>
<link href="newstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">

<!-- our form -->  
<form id='userForm' class="form">
    <div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>
<div id='response'></div>
</div>
<!-- where the response will be displayed -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#response').html("<b>Validating Email...</b>");

        /*
         * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
         */
        $.post('test.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#response').html(data);

        }).fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

***StyleSheet***

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300);

@prim: #53e3a6;

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-weight: 300;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;

    ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            color:    white;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
         color:    white;
         opacity:  1;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
         color:    white;
         opacity:  1;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
         color:    white;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
}

.wrapper{
    background: #50a3a2;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    overflow: hidden;

    &.form-success{
        .container{
            h1{
                transform: translateY(85px);
            }
        }
    }
}

.container{
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;

    h1{
        font-size: 40px;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-put;
        font-weight: 200;
    }
}

form{
    padding: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    input{
        display: block;
        appearance: none;
        outline: 0;
        border: 1px solid fade(white, 40%);
        background-color: fade(white, 20%);
        width: 250px;

        border-radius: 3px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;

        color: white;

        transition-duration: 0.25s;
        font-weight: 300;

        &:hover{
            background-color: fade(white, 40%);
        }

        &:focus{
            background-color: white;
            width: 300px;

            color: @prim;
        }
    }

    button{
        appearance: none;
        outline: 0;
        background-color: white;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        color: @prim;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 250px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
        transition-duration: 0.25s;

        &:hover{
            background-color: rgb(245, 247, 249);
        }
    }
}

.bg-bubbles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    z-index: 1;

    li{
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: fade(white, 15%);
        bottom: -160px;

        -webkit-animation: square 25s infinite;
        animation:         square 25s infinite;

        -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
        transition-timing-function: linear;

        &:nth-child(1){
            left: 10%;
        }

        &:nth-child(2){
            left: 20%;

            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;

            animation-delay: 2s;
            animation-duration: 17s;
        }

        &:nth-child(3){
            left: 25%;
            animation-delay: 4s;
        }

        &:nth-child(4){
            left: 40%;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;

            animation-duration: 22s;

            background-color: fade(white, 25%);
        }

        &:nth-child(5){
            left: 70%;
        }

        &:nth-child(6){
            left: 80%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;

            animation-delay: 3s;
            background-color: fade(white, 20%);
        }

        &:nth-child(7){
            left: 32%;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;

            animation-delay: 7s;
        }

        &:nth-child(8){
            left: 55%;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;

            animation-delay: 15s;
            animation-duration: 40s;
        }

        &:nth-child(9){
            left: 25%;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;

            animation-delay: 2s;
            animation-duration: 40s;
            background-color: fade(white, 30%);
        }

        &:nth-child(10){
            left: 90%;
            width: 160px;
            height: 160px;

            animation-delay: 11s;
        }
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
@keyframes square {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0); }
  100% { transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg); }
}
```

Comment: In which place do you have problem with the style?

Comment: Does the console gives a 404 not found style sheet error? Is the file located in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: Did you compile your LESS stylesheet to CSS?

Comment: @juzraai No... what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can try.

First, make sure that your HTML and CSS files are in same folder.
Second, your attached CSS file is a Less file and not compiled. You must select "View Compiled CSS" from your link of codepen and then copy it.

I hope it would help you